# Send events between two Qt windows

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a Qt application named `my-app`. And I start it by typing in the terminal:

```
./my-app
```

Now I want to send an event between two independent windows from the same application. So, suppose that I have two terminal tabs and I start `my-app` by typing:

```
./my-app 1
./my-app 2
```

Can the first instance of the app (`./my-app 1`) send an event to the second one, and when the second window receives this event to print something in the terminal using `qDebug()` (maybe using  the second argument passed in `args`)?

If yes, how?

Comment: Communication over the QTcpSocket?

Comment: @vahancho I don't know. I imagine something like `jQuery.on('eventName', handler)` & `jQuery.trigger('eventName');`. I would choose the simplest way... I am not a Qt professionist..

Comment: From your question I conclude that even it is the same application, but there are two different instances of it, so you have to consider the IPC between them.

Comment: @vahancho Yes, they are two (or more) different windows (instances), so I have no idea how can they communicate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt provides various ways of communicating between apps. If the applications are to be run on the same machine, then I recommend you take a look at using [QLocalServer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qlocalserver.html) and [QLocalSocket](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qlocalsocket.html).

The first instance of the application can look to see if it can connect to a QLocalServer and if it fails, create its own.

It's not too hard to work with and if you look at the Qt examples, you should find a QLocalSocket example that will demonstrate how to use it.

On Windows, QLocalSockets use named pipes, so non-Qt apps could also connect to it too.

The [fortuneServer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-fortuneserver.html) example from Qt shows how you can use QTcpSocket and QTcpServer and the interface is almost identical for QLocalSocket and QLocalServer

Answer (score 2):

Even if you use the same application, you run more than one instances of it, so that you need to implement communication between the processes. In this regard I would suggest to read the [following paragraphs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/ipc.html) from the Qt documentation.